# How can I exclude a request URI from redirection?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all page requests to another domain, but exclude some request URI which I want to redirect separately. So I have tried something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?id=132$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?id=133$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://new-domain.com/? [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /index.php?id=132 https://new-domain.com/example
Redirect 301 /index.php?id=133 https://new-domain.com/example2
```

But this is not working, can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` variable or `Redirect` directive doesn't match query string.

You can use it like this with a better regex:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index\.php\?id=13[23][&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new-domain.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=132[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new-domain.com/example? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=133[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new-domain.com/example2? [L,R=301]
```

Also note use of `?` in target URL to discard previous query string.

Comment: But can you tell me why it does not work, if I add some other conditions like:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index\.php\?id=13[23][&\s] [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index\.php\?id=41[&\s] [NC]
...

It seems that the first condition is still working, but the second condition is not working :(.

Comment: Since this is negation, you need to `OR` from your condition.